# Ubuntu Server turns off every 15 Minutes since installing updates

Tags: hibernate

My Ubuntu Server turns off every 15 Minutes I guess since installing the updates.

I don't understand what the problem is but I found this in the log:

/var/log/syslog:Jan  3 12:19:56 poseidon systemd-sleep[5168]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)

Comment: If it's set to a max performance state, it may be overheating and then shutting itself down to protect the hardware. Check /var/log/syslog* for what happens just before a power off/shutdown. Check for temp notifications. What OS/version?

Comment: Adding lm-sensors then running `watch sensors` in a terminal lets you watch for overheating. When you reply, please click [edit] and enhance your question with updated info. Please do not use Add Comment since you lose all formatting.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a server, I assume you don't want it to ever go into a low-power state. In that case, issue the following command to disable all:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: +1 However, the log message mentioned is *not* telling it's going to sleep. It's putting the system in a max performance state (level 254).

Comment: That worked out for me! Thank you so much

Comment: In that case, please express your thanks by marking the answer as accepted!